# Sharing information from 2 WordPress websites

Tags: sql, wordpress, triggers

I have 2 WordPress websites that each have hundreds of products in their SQL databases. Each have totally separate resources, but one of these websites is a subdomain of the other and the products on both sites should be identical at all times. How can I achieve this? Should I find a way to merge the two databases together using different prefixes for each site? Should I set triggers in the tables that need to be the same to update their counterpart if one has a row that is updated/added/removed? Is there some other option that I'm not aware of? They use hundreds of identical images as well, is there some way to have them share a common media folder to prevent duplicate pictures?

Thank you in advance for any help you can give.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by, "totally separate resources"?

Answer (score 0):

Some thought about your case:

1. Connecting to same database tables is wrong idea and can create some troubles then.
2. Inserting both website tables into one database can solve this problem. But second website should work on SQL based queries, not on WP API functions.
3. The best solution for your case is using WP REST API.  It means this: First website is normal WP website with products and some data. Second website is programmed working with first website data: through WP REST API. In this case you will not have any conflict, duplicates, troubles.  The main difficulty of this way is needing create new theme which works with RESTful API.